# Logging in to phpmyadmin - docker

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

Hi i am having trouble logging into phpmyadmin on localhost port 8080.

These are the steps i have carried out:

Running an sql container

```
~$ docker run -d mysql/mysql-server
```

I then use docker logs to get the generated password.

I ran this command to enter sql:

```
$ docker exec -it ce9a316 mysql -uroot -p
```

I then changed the password with this command:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysql-password';
```

I then run my phpadmin and link this container to the sql

```
docker run --name phpmyadmin -d --link ce9a316046f0:db -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin
```

I am then trying to login to phpmyadmin on port 8080 with username: root and the password set above but it wont let me login. any help is much appricated.

Answer (score 0):

This command fixed the issue:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```